# I have Enconter a Error in adding and using packages of julia at compiling it show cannot open the file

Tags: julia, flux.jl, julia-pkg

```
julia> using Flux, Plots
[ Info: Precompiling Flux [587475ba-b771-5e3f-ad9e-33799f191a9c]
ERROR: LoadError: could not open file /root/.julia/packages/NNlib/FAI3o/deps/deps.jl
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like this is trying to write to the home directory of the `root` user?  Did you ever start Julia as `root`?

Comment: @Laukik, can you please include the output you get as text instead of an image? (You can just edit you question.)